# Acronis to backup/restore Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-7, backup, osx-snow-leopard, acronis-trueimage

I have Macbook Pro with SL and Bootcamped Windows7 installed as dual boot. I wonder if anyone used Acronis True Image Home or other products to have a backup of all disk, including SL and Windows7 partition.

Answer (score 1):

Acronis won't boot correctly on a MacBook Pro.

Use SuperDuper or CarbonCopyCloner to backup your SL partition and WinClone to backup your Boot Camp partition.

You could also boot from your Mac OS X DVD and use Disk Utility to create an image of your whole hard drive but this can be slow and less flexible.

Comment: WinClone is retired software :( Also in the website `There have been issues reported both with cloning Windows 7 and with running Winclone on Snow Leopard (10.6).`. So still would like to have some other options...

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't noticed it had been retired. :(

My only suggestion is the alternative I proposed above. Boot from a Mac OS X Install DVD and use Disk Utility to create an image of the hard drive (not the individual partitions). You will then be able to restore from this image once you have used Disk Utility's "Scan Image for Restore..." function in the "Images" menu. If you fail to do this the image can be mounted but cannot used for a full restore.

It may also be possible to use one of the other bootable OSS disk imagers but this is not something I have tried myself.