# Backup Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, software-rec

Is there any single software (or at least two) to backup Snow Leopard and Windows 7 on a single Macbook Pro?

Comment: still looking for software recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [winclone](http://download.cnet.com/Winclone/3000-2242_4-172338.html?tag=mncol) to create a clone of the windows partition into a file on the OS X partition, then use Time Machine to backup the OS X partition, on which the windows partition is cloned file. This accomplishes your criteria of littlest software, and it accomplishes the backup to a single location.

Answer (score 2):

If by "at least two" you mean "at most two", and if by that you mean "what software should I use to back up windows and what should I use to back up OS X", then yes, they each have their own respective built-in way to do so. In Windows it's called Windows Backup and Restore, and is in the control panel, though you can access it by just typing "backup" into the start menu. In OS X, it's called TimeMachine, and is in the control panel or you can access it by typing Time Machine into spotlight.

Comment: I would prefer some 3rd party software which will do backup of partition, so no matter how much the OS will be demaged I will be able to recover it.

Comment: I don't see why third party software would do any better of a job. Windows' backup tool does a full image backup - it can even restore to a completely new hard drive and everything will be back exactly how it was; I've done that before. I haven't personally used TimeMachine, but I've seen others use it, and it can do the same thing - full backup of the entire partition. The hard drive could literally explode into fire, and if you had used either of these backups, you could have your computer running just as it was as soon as you got a new hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

By "SL" I guess you mean Snow Leopard? Asking precise questions helps you get better answers... Anyway:

You can use a disk backup tool like [Acronis True Image Home](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/) to back up any and all parts of a harddrive into one disk image in one fell swoop. You can then restore this image to the same disk later, or to a new disk. Or you can extract individual files from the image if you just need that.

Comment: "SL" is a pretty common way to shorten "Snow Leopard" nowadays though I think.

Comment: I've never used OSX and had to stop and think for a moment. But hey, I guessed it eventually :-)

Comment: No need to guess, I initially mentioned Snow Leopard in tag. Acronis won't work on Macbook Pro as far as I know. I'm aware of it, have it and using it for ages on Windows.

Comment: You ought to be able to back up the Mac drives with it too, from within Windows. Granted, this gives you more of a recovery solution than data backup...

Comment: @torbengb: Have you tried it on Macbook? please check this: http://superuser.com/questions/180844/acronis-to-backup-restore-macbook-pro/180882#180882

Comment: Moreover, Acronis support guys clearly states that Mac OS is not supported: http://forum.acronis.com/forum/9642

Comment: Interesting; every OS except OSX is supported, because OSX doesn't use BIOS but EFI... Didn't know that. http://forum.acronis.com/forum/9642#comment-25419